# WPF Change whole application culture at runtime?

Tags: .net, wpf, culture

I have a big WPF application with the requirement of having a menu to switch the language/culture at runtime. It is used for text localization, but also for units (ex: KMH/MPH using the Culture's `RegionInfo` `IsMetric` property) and even generating some URLs for example opening the user manual pdf in the proper language.

In .NET 4.7.2, I had this solution that was working perfectly:

```cs
var language = XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(culture.Name);
foreach (Window childWindow in Application.Current.Windows)
{
    childWindow.Dispatcher.Thread.CurrentCulture = culture;
    childWindow.Dispatcher.Thread.CurrentUICulture = culture;
    childWindow.Language = language;
}

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = culture;
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = culture;

LocalizeDictionary.Instance.Culture = culture;
```

`LocalizeDictionary` is part of the [XAMLMarkupExtensions](https://github.com/XAMLMarkupExtensions) nuget and allows to refresh all localization bindings instantly.

Unfortunately, since moving to NET6 and adding a bit of async code in there, it stopped working properly.

It does change the current thread culture, all new threads cultures and even refresh the current opened windows cultures.

The problem is, it seems like already running threads don't get updated, and the application now try to re-use them more than it did before instead of creating new ones. So if I put breakpoints in, let's say a button command and check the culture, it still shows the old one. Same for creating a new view model for a new window, it seems to be created using the old culture.

I've seen quite a few answers mentioning this line:

```cs
FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(FrameworkElement), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(language));
```

Unfortunately, this needs to be set in a static context once for the whole application, it can't be changed at runtime (`PropertyMetadata is already registered for type 'FrameworkElement'.`). And I don't think this really is the issue, because looping on current windows and changing the `Language` property seems to do the same. My problem seems to lie in existing background threads, not WPF elements in themselves.

I tried to find a way to find all existing threads, but only managed to get OS threads with `Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads` and not Managed Threads, so no way to change their culture via that method.

Any way to list all existing threads and change their culture? Or force WPF to run commands on new threads instead of re-using them?

Comment: There are questions about enumerating managed threads.   The proposed solutions seem unreliable at best.     You cannot "force WPF to run commands on new threads short always of explicitly creating those threads yourself.  And any existing calls to `Task.Run` are not going to use your mechanism.  So how realistic is it for you to convince the powers-that-be in your company that a localization change requires re-starting the app?  Is  changing this a common scenario for the users of your app?

Comment: Yes it is, we switch between views representing organizations in different parts of the world regularly, and everything from units to date format needs to follow. Relaunching the application every time would be a massive waste of time and wouldn't cut the requirements. It's also a shame because it's a regression from a functional feature before the framework upgrade, and customers aren't happy about it. You are also right that solutions about listing managed threads  requiring to attach a debugger are kinda unreliable.

Comment: I don't know if it helps but I just looked at the code for the `ResourceManager` class.  According to the comments *The Resource
Manager will use CultureInfo.GetCurrentUICulture() to look up a resource for your user's locale settings.*

The `ResourceManager.CurrentUiCulture` has a setter as well as a getter   And every instance of .resx-generated code seems to have an `ResourceManager` property that refers to the global instance.  All of this is to say: if you problem were merely limited to code looking up the wrong language strings, you could probably fix it with this

Comment: Regardless the source code is available for you to look at .  Maybe you can find the appropriate setters for your needs just with a few judicious uses of Visual Studio's "Go to Definition"...?

Comment: Sorry RessourceManager is not the problem here, but the thread current culture in my viewmodels is.

Comment: Wait... for your ***view-models***?  Are you saying your own code caches a culture value somewhere and *that* is not getting updated?  That's the problem?

Comment: Commands creates viewmodel and open other child windows. Those have bound objects in the views not using the correct culture. You know, when it calls ToString() on a type like DateTime it's not using the new culture.

Comment: MVVM architectural pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, the code above changing the culture on the threads/default/dispatchers/window xml works, but when ran from a normal event handler or command.

In my situation, it was run in an async command (with the help of ReactiveUI library ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask()) and doing it in that context would not keep the changes. Not even if I invoked the WPF dispatcher from inside that task. All following event/commands and even bound property getter would get called with the old culture.

So I can't explain the details, but if your culture changes don't apply, check on which context you are doing the operation.

Also, it is useless to loop on every windows. You can just set it on the Application.Current.MainWindow